# Instance Variable only in one row in Java

Tags: java, instance-variables

Hi stackoverflow members,
Do you know why an instance variable in a Java Class must be declared only in one line and not in 2?
for example:

```
String ring;
ring = "indeed";
```

It gives a compilation error. Why is it not allowed?
It is senseless doing it as I did in this example, however it might be useful using that procedure to initialize the variable inherited from a superclass without using the sub-class constructor.

for example:

```
class Ringo{
String ring;
}
class RingoStar extends Ringo{
ring = "That's how to play drums";
}
```

Obviously it gives a compilation error. That's the point, Does anyone know why it is not allowed?

Comment: @JanDvorak Hi Jan, do you mean that putting that code in a Java Class as instance variable works fine for you?

Comment: @Everyone does anybody know why it's mandatory an init block or specifying it in the constructor?

Comment: `ring = "indeed";` is not in an initialization block, constructor or method. So, when do you think it should be executed at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have what you want with a slightly different syntax. Consider:

```
class Ringo{
 String ring;

 { 
  ring = "indeed";
 }
}
```

I guess the answer to your very question is that Java syntax doesn't allow for having just any statement within the class body. You need to use initializer blocks as shown above (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's technically possible if you wrap the assignment in curly brackets:

```
String ring;
{
    ring = "indeed";
}
```

The assignment gets executed before any constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between declaration and initialization. Declaration is a allocation and addressing thing. Initialization is a filling the memory with information. It has to be represented by different syntax and rules.

A language also needs to take care of aesthetics. When Java was written, I guess this was the demand for aesthetics. When the architects of Pascal rewrote .NET C#, they did it differently I guess. Learnt from both Java and Pascal.

Comment: "_When the same architects rewrote .NET C#_": Who says .NET C# was created by the same architects?

Comment: My bad, it was Anders Hejlsberg, architect of Pascal.

Answer (score 0):

There are two completely separate aspects to a Java file:

- declarations, acted upon at compile time;
- executive code, acted upon at runtime.

A single line such as

```
private int x = 1;
```

may look like it's all about executive code ("it creates an instance variable"), but in fact it has both aspects to it, which are in fact widely separated in terms of the time when their make their effect. In Java no variables are ever created at runtime, like they are for example in Ruby.

When you keep that in mind, you'll develop the right intuition that the former line is very different in nature from

```
x = 1;
```

in the middle of class body.